# How to force the browser to stop parsing dynamically inserted code to HTML 4?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xhtml

I actually need to parse some really old HTML to a PDF file, I already have a jar that does this, but it only accepts legit XHTML code. So i have to parse my old HTML code so the jar will accept it. As I know very well how the HTML-code that I parse will look like my idea was to use the [HTML-Parser by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/) to parse certain tags (img, br, meta) with it to straight XML, which will have the needed effect (mostly closing tags) on them.

My actual attempt looks like this:

```
function fixTags() {
    var tagsToParse = new Array( "br", "img", "input", "meta" );

    for(i = 0; i < tagsToParse.length; i++) {
        var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tagsToParse[i]);
        for(j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
                elements[j].outerHTML = HTMLtoXML(elements[j].outerHTML);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the browser will interpret the new code for the element as HTML4, which leads him to changing back the stuff that i wanted to change. For example a `<br>` becomes a `<br/>` after going through the parser, but the browser will actually interpret this as HTML4 and the outerHTML property of the element will be `<br>` again.

My first attempt to solve this was to force the document to be XHTML temporarily:

```
var root = document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0];
root.setAttribute("xml", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
```

but this doesn't seem to bother the browser at all in his behaviour.

The "obvious" solution of building a string-tree out of the dom, replacing the strings there and traversing the tree to the string I want seems a bit too heavy and complex for this "little" problem, that's why I ask you.

So if someone has an idea for an easier solution, I would be very happy, the application is IE-only so IE-exclusive solutions are accepted as well.

Comment: If you don't like the way a browser serializes your DOM to HTML, then I think you'll just need to write your own serializer, which isn't too difficult. But if the issue is that you need valid HTML5, then there should be no issue with `<br>`.

Comment: The problem is actually how the browser interprets the HTML-code that is set dynamically to the DOM (inputting "<br/>" will result in a DOM-ELement with the text "<br>"). I need all tags to be closed which is XHTML and not HMTL 5, youre right with that and I will edit. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, the elements themselves don't keep their original HTML, so the browser reads the DOM and serializes it however it wants when you use `.outerHTML`. I don't know of any way to change it. DOM serialization isn't that hard though. Just make a recursive function that turns an element into an HTML string in whatever for you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case, it's probably easiest to use an existing HTML -> XHTML converter, for example: http://www.it.uc3m.es/jaf/html2xhtml/simple-form.html

If you really want to do this in the browser, for a naive solution you could try something like this, using naive regexes (you shouldn't generally use RegExp to parse XML) and XMLSerializer.

```
var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
var xml = serializer.serializeToString(document).replace(/<(img|meta|input|br|link)([^>]*)/gi, function (ignore, tagName, attributes) {
    return '<' + tagName + attributes + ' />';
});
```

You can look up a less naive regex if that doesn't work, but I think for a document that can be converted to PDF in the first place that should do the trick.

EDIT: Note that the RegEx assumes that none of those tags are self-closing before this operation.